# Find java PID using batch

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, pid

I need to know java process PID from Windows batch console.

```
@echo off
set p=%CD%
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%A IN ('"%JAVA_HOME%/bin/jps.exe -v"\|find  "%p%"') DO SET str=%%A
echo str = "%str%"
```

Java process unique identifier is path from what it was executed.
Script executes jps, that returns all java process information, for example

```
9376 Jps -Denv.class.path=D:\tools\timesten\lib\ttjdbc6.jar; -Dapplication.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24 -Xms8m
3856  -Dexe4j.semaphoreName=c:_program files (x86)_jetbrains_intellij idea community edition 12.0.1_bin_idea.exe -Dexe4j.moduleName=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12....etc
```

Batch says that: 
   | was unexpected at this time.

Could you please said ,  how to correctly extract PID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct script

```
   "%JAVA_HOME%/bin/jps.exe" -v>temp.txt
   for /f "tokens=1" %%f in ('find "%CD%" "temp.txt"') do set str=%%f
   echo str=%str%
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the pipe like this `^|` within a `FOR` statement, otherwise it tries to pipe the first half of the `FOR` statement into the second.

Also this is how I would find a PID.

`for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('tasklist ^| find "jps.exe") do set javapid=%%a`

Answer (score 0):

You can user command "tasklist" for show PID。

Comment: I still have to parse this response. Problem is that I need to parse tasklist in for, but I can't